# How to find the element who's xpath change dynamically?

Tags: xpath, protractor

We have element which doesn't have id or name to find while automation testing.
Below is the html code for it.

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="col-md-4">
    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group"> Account Name: </div>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group"> 
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">1234567890</span> 
</div>
```

We found element by using xpath. we can click the element in one case. Here the xpath was,

```
/html/body/app-root/app-root/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/span
```

But in the second case we are unable to find the element ,because new element will in the page. Now the above xpath will change to ,

```
/html/body/app-root/app-root/div/div[4]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/span
```

Now the question how to find the above element?.

Comment: How is this item identified, if not by its position? A specific content?

Comment: Just used xpath to identify

Comment: `//div[@class="form-group"]/span`?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Andersson. But  we have multiple tags with class="form-group". like    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="col-md-4"><div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group"> Account Name: </div></div>                              <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="form-group">
   <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">1234567890</span>
</div>

Comment: Please clarify there is one `Account Name:` on page or multiples?

Comment: only one account name is there.

Comment: @venkatesh, but `//div[@class="form-group"]/span` won't match first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venkatesh from the comment section I understood you want to find the `Account Name` value from the page

You can write xpath with visible text.

```
//*[contains(text()," Account Name: ")]/ancestor::div/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,"form-group")]/span
```

You can find the Preceding `div` with visible text `Account Name:` and later find the following sibling which will hold the `Account Name:` value in it.

Similarly you can find each element by changing the visible text alone.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the xpath in chrome inspector ?

Comment: I had copied your html and checked with it in chrome inspector. It highlighted the value correctly.

Comment: `<div _ngcontent-c1 class="row"><div _ngcontent-c1 class="col-md-4"><div _ngcontent-c1 class="form-group"> Account Number: </div></div><div _ngcontent-c1 class="col-md-4"><div _ngcontent-c1 class="form-group"><span _ngcontent-c1 class="ng-tns-c1-0">9090909090</span></div></div></div>`

Comment: The above is my html.can you please try with that?

Comment: Venkatesh  Please try //*[contains(text()," Account Number: ")]/ancestor::div/following-sibling::div/div[contains(@class,"form-group")]/span

Comment: Account number was having a extra div . I will update the answer with generic xpath for both.

Comment: Can you edit question with entire html and values which you need to fetch ?

Comment: This works perfect bharath. Thank you.Is there any link or documentation to understand the above scenario indetail.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp   here you go. Thanks have a nice day